# How to Change Dns in Android for 3G mobile network?

Tags: android, dns, android-networking

For Example We can Change Dns or other nettwork info using this code

```
public static void setDNS(InetAddress dns, WifiConfiguration wifiConf)
        throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
        NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

    Object linkProperties = getField(wifiConf, "linkProperties");
    if (linkProperties == null)
        return;

    ArrayList<InetAddress> mDnses = (ArrayList<InetAddress>)getDeclaredField(
            linkProperties, "mDnses");
    mDnses.clear(); // or add a new dns address , here I just want to
                    // replace DNS1
    mDnses.add(dns);
}
```

I want to change Dns for 3G mobile netwrok ?please help me out ...
I have tried this one if any one know any class for this plz tell me I will find out more.

```
Context context = DnsCacheService.this.getBaseContext();
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Object prop = cm.getClass().getMethod("getActiveLinkProperties").invoke(cm);
Collection<InetAddress>    currDnses = ((LinkProperties) prop).getDnsServers();
Collection<InetAddress> newDnses = new ArrayList();
InetAddress dnstoAdd = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
newDnses.add(dnstoAdd);
newDnses.add(dnstoAdd);
//prop.setDnsServers(newDnses);
```

Comment: thank you @ArifulHaque  but you have any idea about that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I just corrected the formatting of question. I would sure help you by answering if I was experienced with the problem domain :).